# Making HTTP requests in Angular 8

Tags: asp.net, angular

I'm making http request in angular. but values wont display in web page
   and also i'm using sample free api - https://reqres.in/api
   but this wont display any values.

here is my component.ts

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'app-value',
      templateUrl: './value.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./value.component.css']
    })
    export class ValueComponent implements OnInit {

      values: any;
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.getValues();
      }

      getValues() {
      return this.http.get<any>('https://reqres.in/api/users/2').subscribe(response => {this.values = response.any; });

      }

    }
```

and here is component.html

```
 <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let value of values">
      {{ value.text }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Why do you use 'response.any'? Response is a JSON object with a key of 'data'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get single record, do not user ngFor.

Change response.any to response.data beacuse api returns in JSON 'data' as key not 'any' then in template add for example:

```
<ul>
    <li>
      {{ values.email}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

ngFor you can use, when api return data as object array. Very good solution is using Postman, to check what data API returns, to know what the JSON structure looks like.

Comment: thanks. it worked. i'm a beginner for this and really appreciated for the help :)

Comment: No problem :) Good luck with angular.

Comment: how do i change this if i need to bring list? should i move to ngFor? is there any change need to be done in component.ts?

Comment: Yes, then you must user ngFor. In component you do not have to change anything.

Answer (score 1):

`this.values = response.any` is wrong because your response is an object which has property `data` not `any`.

Also at this endpoint, you are getting a single user, not a collection of users, so you should rename your variable to `value` not `values`.

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'app-value',
      templateUrl: './value.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./value.component.css']
    })
    export class ValueComponent implements OnInit {

      value: any;
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.getValue();
      }

      getValue() {
      return this.http.get<any>('https://reqres.in/api/users/2').subscribe(response => {this.value = response.data; });

      }

    }
```

In HTML you can use the `json async pipe` to present your data as json

```
<div> {{ value | json}} </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. changed response.any to response.data and removed ngFor. now it works fine.thanks :)

Comment: how do i change this if i need to bring list? should i move to ngFor? is there any change need to be done in component.ts?